# Assigning a grade from an array

Tags: c++, arrays

I need to write a program that reads student scores, gets the best score, and then assigns grades based on the following scheme:

1) Grade is A if score is >= best - 10

2) Grade is B if score is >= best - 20;

3) Grade is C if score is >= best - 30;

4) Grade is D if score is >= best - 40;

5) Grade is F otherwise.

The program prompts the user to enter the total number of students, then prompts the user to enter all of the scores, and concludes by displaying the grades.  My problem comes from pulling the grades from an array, this is what I have so far:

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int studentGrade(int* gradeArray, int numberStudents)
{
    int grade = 0;
    int score, best;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberStudents; i++)
    {
        grade += gradeArray[i];
    }

    return (grade);
}
int main()
{
    int numberStudents;
    cout << "Enter the number of students: ";
    cin >> numberStudents;

    int* gradeArray = new int[numberStudents];

    for (int i = 0; i < numberStudents; i++)
    {
        int score;
        cout << "Enter the students Score: ";
        cin >> score;

        gradeArray[i] = score;
        cout << gradeArray[i];
    }


}
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?  Please be more specific.  Also, you are leaking `gradeArray`, since you do not `delete[]` it. Consider using a `std::vector` instead.

Comment: Another problem comes when the input is incorrect! Input should always be checked before it is used: `if (std::cin >> score) { ... } else { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a function other than **main()** you have to call it from main or some other function to us execute it.
Nowhere in your code you called your

```
int studentGrade(int* gradeArray, int numberStudents){}
```

If you want to execute the *studentGrade* function you should call it with appropriate parameters,the call should be from main like--

```
studentGrade(gradeArray,numberStudents);
```

As your studentGrade function will return an int value you can call it like this aslo;

```
int finalGrade=studentGrade(gradeArray,numberStudents);
```

and to print the value returned by studentGrade just:

```
std::cout<<finalGrade<<std::endl;
```

When you will call the function this way your code will simply sum up all the data in array gardeArray and return it.So remaining mathematics you can do yourself.

And as you have allocated memory to array with new you should delete in at the end of your program in following way

```
delete []gradeArray;
```

Moreover that your main function returns a int as you have declared it

```
int main ()
```

so at the end of your code you should have

```
 return 0;
```

So add this in your main after your for loop-

```
 int finalGrade =studentGrade(gradeArray,numberStudents);
 std::cout<<finalGrade<<std::endl;
 delete []gradeArray;
 return 0;
```

Now you can move forward,Goodluck :)

Comment: And as suggested by  Remy Lebeau try using std::vectors.